# Lambda Expressions for filtering in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have three objects:

- Person
- Hobby
- Type

Person.java:

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private List<Hobby> hobbyList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

Hobby.java:

```
public class Hobby
{
    private String name;
    private Person person;
    private Type type;
    ...
}
```

Type.java:

```
public class Type
{
    private String name;
    private List<Hobby> hobbyList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

Between Person and Hobby is a 1:m relation and between Type and Hobby is a 1:m relation.

Now, my problem is, I want to filter a list of Persons using lambda expressions. Only persons with hobbies, which have a specific type should be in the list.

I need to iterate through the persons, in order to get the individual list of hobbies and need to check if a hobby has a specific type.

Without lambda expressions, I would filter the list the following:

```
List<Person> filteredList = new LinkedList<>();
for (Person p : persons)
{
    for (Hobby h : p.getHobbyList())
    {
        if(h.getType.getName.equals("Ball"))
        {
            if(!filteredList.contains(p))
            {
                filteredList.add(p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is there a back-reference from hobby to person? What if X persons have the same hobby? Instead I'd suggest Person ->* Hobby *<->1 Type

Comment: One way, you could get all Person with Hobby that involves the type of name 'Ball' such as:
 `List<Person> typeListMap = persons.stream()
        .flatMap(p -> p.getHobbyList()
                .stream()
                .map(h -> Map.entry(h.getType().getName(), p)))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, 
                        Collectors.toList())))
        .get("Ball");`. Notice that the intermediate `Map` created here gives you a mapping of people based on the type of the hobby they have.

Answer (score 0):

Do it as

```
List<Person> filteredList = persons.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getHobbyList().stream().anyMatch(h -> h.getType().getName().equals("Ball")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**[Update]**

I see that you have updated the question. Based on your update, the following should work for you:

```
Set<Person> filteredSet = persons.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getHobbyList().stream().anyMatch(h -> h.getType().getName().equals("Ball")))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Note that a `Set` automatically discards duplicate values and therefore, you do not need to check `if(!filteredList.contains(p))` in this case.

Comment: @Michael - I agree with you. Thanks.

Comment: He actually edited in a `contains` check, so now it matches

Comment: This isn't type-correct, is it? Looks like the filter function doesn't yield a boolean.

Comment: This is still not working... There is an error with the filter for the HobbyList

Comment: Is there a collect or map missing?

Comment: @MatthäusSchwarzkogler replace the inner `filter` with `anyMatch`.

Comment: Personnally I would add a hasHobby() utility method to Person. Then things would become much simpler.

Comment: @Olivier how about choosing `Set<Hobby> hobbies` in that case? the order matters less often for what hobbies does a person have unless they are ranked, in which case `LinkedHashSet`? :)

Comment: @AndyTurner - Thanks for pointing it out. I've corrected it now.